# Cloudfront/S3 - Limit the content that users can access for static site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-deployment, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static site hosted on a private S3 bucket with cloudfront configured (+ domain/routing). One problem I am noticing is that any user could access all the files in the S3 bucket through cloudfront when they shouldnt have access.

For example, the user should have access to `index.html`, `404.html`, and `about.html`, but not the js and css files (maybe?), or internal files like

[image: s3 bucket]

What is best practice when it comes to what the clients can access? If I do need to restrict access to some files, how would I do that?

Comment: Easiest, would be to keep private files in a different  bucket.

Comment: Just to check, these assets are not needed for the site to run?

Comment: How have you configured this solution? Are you using an Origin Access Identity to grant bucket access to CloudFront?

Comment: Why are you keeping files in that bucket that you do not want them to access?

Comment: I just want to add to the point by Chris Williams; if your HTML files reference any of those other files (css, js, images, etc.), then once a browser loads the HTML it will follow those references and request them from the server. As far as S3 is concerned, there is no difference between a user accessing them directly and a browser requesting them as a resource. If they’re used by your HTML pages, you can’t block them without breaking your site.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys for all the comments. These files are indeed files needed to make the site run. I just thought it would be better design/practice to only let users access the html files/pages instead of internal js css files.